# laravel memory limit on two level relationship query with cache

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relationship

Hoping someone can offer some advice.

I have this query:

```
Branch::with('users.books')->orderBy('name','asc')->get();
```

But when trying to cache it I'm getting:

> Out of memory (allocated 961019904) (tried to allocate 441764623
>   bytes)

So it's not actually using all the memory it's allocated anyway - To cache it i'm simply:

```
$branches = Cache::remember('branches-reports', 1440, function() {
        return Branch::with('users.books')->orderBy('name','asc')->get();
});
```

I'm not sure how I can get around this.

Relationship wise a user can have one branch and a branch can have many users. Then the relationship between the books and users is a many to many using a pivot table.

any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: How many rows does the query return?

Comment: Not 100% sure but there are around 585 records in the books_users pivot table. 25 Branches and 2000 users. So not huge amounts.

Comment: And about 6 books at the moment. So not much at all.

Comment: Typically, in my experience, the error message you are receiving is thrown on indefinite recursion. Have you tried injecting only around 10 elements to DB and seeing if the error persists?

Comment: I tried doing a take(10) and it will work. Fails when it gets up to 20+.